# Load ListView with JSON data from URL

Tags: android, json, android-listview, android-asynctask

I have following scenario:

- I develop an Android Application which has a ListView in the MainActivity
- The data for populating the ListView comes from a URL returning JSON data
- I want to "cache" the ListView items as long as possible (depending on the cache control header of the URL resource), which means that I do not want to reload the ListView data (from the external URL) each time the user goes back to the MainActivity

I found this article: [Android AsyncTask ListView - JSON|Surviving w/ Android](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/01/android-async-listview-jee-and-restful.html) which is good, but not excatly what I want. I do not want to execute the AsyncTask each time the user comes back to the MainActivity.

I thought of storing the ListView items in a globally available parameter of the Application. This parameter would then be some sort of custom container which holds the ListItems and the timestamp at which they expire. Then it would be possible to check in the "doInBackground" method of the AsyncTask if the ListView items are valid. If yes they are returned, if not they are loaded from URL and saved to the global variables.

My question: Does this solution make sense? How would you solve this? Any ideas on making this better?

Comment: I think you have check for updated or latest data when user came to your List Activity which have two possibility 1.if list data loaded first time than user have to wait until data loaded from server and cache in database and 2.check for latest or updated data from server this checking run in background user ui is not block this data given from local cache.

Comment: I dont want to cache the JSON data in the database. I do not need to store the data persistently. On each Application start I download the data from the URL again. This is because of up-to-date reasons. Also I do not need to synchronize data from JSON to the database. This would be a not necessary overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yours make sense; however, I'd like to add something.

For coding part,

- Cache the JSON each time your request done successfully. You probably gonna need to use `LruCache` that should be defined in your custom `Application` class. Each key/value pair store the data model after parsing JSON. For example, `cache.put(model.id, model)`.

For UX part,

- You don't need to update JSON every time, but provide an action trigger to do it. Some common ways is:

  - Provide a refresh button somewhere on screen? (Could be an item on `ActionBar`...)
  - Application starts execution.
  - Users pull down the `ListView` to refresh content.
  - ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The displayed items represent news items. Therefore I rather let the Application do the updating. In my understanding a user does not want to update news. He wants to see the most current news at any given time. The AsyncTask starts always and checks if the data is still valid, and if not it pulls the new data. So there is no need for the user to update.

Comment: As for the LruCache: Is it significantly better to use LruCache instead of a globally available Application variable? Does this make a lot of difference?

Comment: Well, as in your use-case like that, I personally tend to use a `Service` to check for latest news, for example, 10 min-per-check. The continuous request will kill the battery, it gonna die real fast as in my experiences.

Comment: The JSON data on the server has a cache control header which is valid at least half an hour. This in reverse implies that the AsyncTask, after the first loading of the data from the URL, does not need to pull new data, as it is cached in the Application. So there ist not so much battery consumption, I assume.

Comment: well, I have no idea. You'd better give it a shot first to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Since the ListView data is already serialized as JSON when you retrieve it, I think your best best is to persist the JSON. Android handles persisting strings in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). You could also use SharedPreferences to persist the keepalive timestamp, allowing you to determine when you should refresh the data.

This will allow you to populate the ListView between application loads as well as between activities without querying the server.

Comment: I am not sure if I like the idea of storing my JSON data in the SharedPreferences. I think this is poor design. My first application also did that, but I was not very happy with this behaviour. I rather use globally Application variables for storing data which only needs to be available during the Applications lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var api={
        getapicallForCategories(){
            var url='your url';
           return fetch(url).then((res)=>res.json()); 
        },
        
        };
        
        module.exports=api;
```

```js
 componentDidMount() {
        api.getapicallForCategories().then((res) => {
            this.setState({
                listdata: res,
            })  
        });
    }
    
    
    //inside render
     for (var m = 0; m < this.state.listdata.length; m++) {
                this.state.listdataCategory[m] = this.state.listdata[m].Category;
                this.state.listdataPrice[m] = this.state.listdata[m].Amt;

                const details = {
                    name: this.state.listdataCategory[m],
                    price: this.state.listdataPrice[m],
                }
                list.push(details);

            }
            
            
 //   inside return
  {
                            list.map((l, i) => (
                                <ListItem

                                    key={i}
                                    title={l.name}
                                    subtitle={l.price}


                                    rightIcon={<Icon name={'add-circle'} style={{ color: '#006400', fontSize: 40 }} onPress={() => this.onIncrease(l.price, i)} />}
                                    avatar={<Icon name={'remove-circle'} style={{ color: '#FF0000', fontSize: 40 }} onPress={() => this.onRemove(l.price, i)} />}

                                />

                            ))


                        }
```